# Measure the volume of a bag using balls?

Tags: geometry, volume

I would like to measure the volumes of these three bags because the given values don't make sense (Feel free to guess the volume/rank them by size in the comments. I will update the question with the true values in a couple of days). One way, I imagine, to do that would be to get a lot of tennis balls or similar and see how many that fit into each bag. That way you can get a pretty exact relative size (if one bag can hold 10 balls and another 15 balls, the latter is 1,5 times bigger) but that doesn't answer the question "what is the actual volume in litres?" because there will be a lot of empty space between the balls.

**Is it possible to give a good estimate of how much space there are between the balls if they are packed in a perfect way?** The exact size of the balls is known.

(Are there other ways than balls to estimate the size in this situation? The bags are not watertight, and besides, if you load them with 50 to 100 kg of water I think they will break.)

[image: Three bags]

Comment: Not really an estimation strategy, but if you can find the manufacturer or a retail listing, then those usually have the interior volume listed in the specs.

Comment: The density of perfect sphere packing is known (74%). However, if you just fill the bags with balls, they probably won't line up perfectly. In that case, you may need to look at [random sphere packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_close_pack)

Comment: @Angelica, I think the asker doubts the accuracy of those listed specs, and is looking for independent verification.

Comment: @dbx That is exactly the situation.

Comment: Here is a suggestion that avoids irregular arrangements of objects that have gaps between them: fill a bag with clothes, then take the clothes out and fold and put them in a box. Then you can measure the volume of the part of the box that is filled with clothes.

Comment: 1 = 60 l, 2 = 90 l (50 % bigger than 1!!), 3 = 70 l. I don't believe the given volumes for 1 and 2 are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say all your tennis balls have the exact same volume $V$, and they don't get squished in the bag.

If you pour the tennis balls in the bag randomly roughly $40\%$ of the bag will be empty. If you shake the bag and add more balls it will be approximately $36\%$ empty. Source:[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_close_pack]

So, lets suppose that the bag is full of tennis balls, and $36\%$ empty. In order words, the tennis balls only account for $64\%$ of the total volume.

Then, if you add $n$ balls the total volume of the bag is $nV*\frac{100}{64}$.

This is a bit awkward because you have to try add the balls to the bag as randomly as possible. If you think you are able to pack them efficiently, the volume will be $nV*\frac{100}{76}$. This is because the densest packing of spheres will leave $24\%$ empty space. So the real answer will be somewhere in the range $\frac{100nV}{76}$ to $\frac{100nV}{64}$.

Comment: Thank you, that answer was as exact as the precision of the estimate of the volume I needed.

Comment: @d-b How did it work out? Were the specs accurate?

Comment: @dbx First I need to find 150 tennis balls :-)